# IMPORT ALL CSV FILE TO MYSQL DATABASE

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my SQL Script.

```
use trans;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/NANTRANS/TRANSPORT/DATA1.csv' INTO TABLE `IUBIP` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 8 LINES;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/NANTRANS/TRANSPORT/DATA2.csv' INTO TABLE `IUBIP` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 8 LINES;
```

When i import that SQL script to my database, i want all of CSV file in Folder TRANSPORT will be import in database. however sometime my CSV files have random filename, sometime DATA1.CSV, DATA001.CSV, DATA9.CSV, etc. so how to import all of csv files? I try use *.csv but it doesn't work. HELP.

Comment: why not make a small script to find csv files and import them one by one ?

Comment: You can't do this from mysql without writing custom compiled user defined function created in c or c++. It is easier to create an externsl script that imports the files one by one.